# Splitting figures/tables into separate files

Tags: tables, floats

I'm preparing an article for submission in a journal and it requires that the PDF of the text be uploaded without figures and tables and each figure and table should be it's own PDF file complete with caption/title.

How can I make it so the figures and tables do not appear in the main PDF but the references to them are still valid when I compile the text? Do I have to tell it to put all floats at the end, each on their own page, and then split those out of the PDF so the references in the body work? Is there another trick to doing it?

Comment: I proposed a working solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383255/33634

Answer (score 3):

More experimenting has lead to the use of the [endfloat](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/endfloat/endfloat.pdf) package. This moves all of the figures and tables to the end with their own page for each, that can then be split out of the PDF file using other software. Just adding the `\usepackage{endfloat}` to the preamble makes it work, although the default options may need changed.

For my particular application and to facilitate splitting out the pages later, I also suppressed the page numbering on the float pages by adding `\AtBeginDelayedFloats{\pagenumbering{gobble}}`

Comment: Of course, this is one way to do it. I'm open to suggestions and other techniques.