# Generating a separate pdf file of tables and figures from a latex file?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats, pdftex, pdf

Is it possible to generate a PDF of figures and tables of a paper from LaTeX itself?

I saw Journals and Conferences asking for a separate file of tables and figures.

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134733/splitting-figures-tables-into-separate-files) question, questioner proposed a method that uses `\usepackage{endfloat}` to push all the figures and tables to the last pages and then use a PDF editor to cut the last pages of PDF. This is a solution but not a good one. LaTeX should be able to do this by its own.

What I have in mind is to compile the LaTeX file and it generates a complete PDF output and beside that a separate file that contains all the figures and tables of former PDF.

Comment: Do you want only a single pdf with all figures? Or do you want a single pdf with all figures inserted as in the document, with captions and numbers and margins, etc...?

Comment: @Sigur I think your second option includes the first one. but in my case both options are good.

Comment: I asked because: 1. if you use only pdf figures and 2. if you use linux then you can simply copy all figures to one tempo folder or rename them staring with `fig` and use the terminal to run `pdftk fig*.pdf cat output all-figs.pdf` for example. Thus you will have all pdf glued together.

Comment: @Sigur very good solution for figures. Thanks. but what about tables? I think a generic solution for separating figure and tables with latex itself maybe available. lots of journals and conference ask for this. it's common.

Comment: Some years ago I used `VerbatimOut` to produce verbatim codes and create an external file contained exactly the code so I could compile those external files later. Maybe you can adapt it to produce your tables.

Comment: Make the tables in separate `.tex` files and include with `\input{table1}` between the main text and in a empty document. Is this way the main text is more readable for humans and the document only with tables is very easy to do. Of course, thi is also valid for for the figures.

Comment: If you had used `\input` to include each table (e.g., `\input table01.tex`) and kept them all separate, it would be easy to create a `table-wrapper.tex` that also input the same tables.  Then a simple `Makefile` would generate both the regular .pdf and the table-wrapper.pdf. Same with the figures....

Comment: @jon,@Fran, good solution. But it's shortcoming is that it's hard to modify and separate all the tables and codes for big files. In my case it's less than 10 tables but what if somebody who is writing a book forgot to separate the codes or tables in the first place?

Comment: Well, I'd say s/he is missing out on a big virtue of using TeX in the first place. Simply put, don't use/create 'big files'!  Monolithic files make little sense and a reliance on them is either due to still being caught in a 'word processor'-like mentality and/or on a mediocre text editor.  Of course, out of intellectual curiosity, I'd like to see the solution you are hoping for (so +1 for the question), but it is very unlikely to be the solution I'd recommend at the end of the day.

Comment: @sajjadG. I agree with jon. If worth make subfiles even with a big document already well advanced. I take only a seconds search `\begin{table}`, add  `\input{tableXXX}` just before, select until `\end{table}`, cut  the whole float and paste in the new document `tableXXX.tex`. With a good editor may be you can automatize most of this procedure with a macro.

Comment: @Fran I agree with jon too. I always use separate files and `\input` them in the main file. But others don't. I'm doing this right now but as I said it's not a good solution for big files. +1 for mentioning macro. that's would be a good idea for large files. I don't know how to use macro in editors I use (texmaker, vim, gedit). for now with my 6 page conference paper I can copy paste them but for the 30 page journal paper I will get board from copying and pasting and I'll wish for and easier solution. the best one is a simple latex command `\separatePDF{figures,tables}{filename.pdf}` :)

Comment: I proposed a solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383255/33634

Answer (score 19):

The following code will extract all graphics and floats. To prove it, I load the extracted objects again with `\includepdf` (see the animation).

```
% this file name is extractor.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape extractor
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,\placeholder]{preview}
%\PreviewEnvironment{\placeholder}
\PreviewBorder=12pt\relax


\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
\hline
    11 & 12 & 13\\
    21 & 22 & 23\\
    31 & 32 & 33\\
    41 & 42 & 43\\
    51 & 52 & 53\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}


\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6-10]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[16-20]


\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor,pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in{graphics,floats}{%
    \immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=template-\x\space "\def\noexpand\placeholder{\x} \noexpand\input{template}"}%
    \includepdf[pages=-]{template-\x}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code above just simulates your scenario. To apply it in your real scenario, do the following.

### Step 1

Assume that your input file is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
\hline
    11 & 12 & 13\\
    21 & 22 & 23\\
    31 & 32 & 33\\
    41 & 42 & 43\\
    51 & 52 & 53\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6-10]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[16-20]

\end{document}
```

### Step 2

Insert

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage,graphics]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=12pt\relax
```

in your input file. So your input file becomes as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,graphics]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=12pt\relax

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
\hline
    11 & 12 & 13\\
    21 & 22 & 23\\
    31 & 32 & 33\\
    41 & 42 & 43\\
    51 & 52 & 53\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6-10]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[16-20]

\end{document}
```

Save this input file as `anyfilename-graphics.tex`

### Step 3

Invoke `pdflatex anyfilename-graphics` to obtain a PDF file containing all extracted graphics.

### Step 4

Repeat Step 2  but replace `graphics` with `floats`, save the file as `anyfilename-floats.tex`. Now compile with `pdflatex anyfilename-floats` to get a PDF file containing all extracted floats (figure or table).

### Step 5

Done!

Comment: More complex, but awesome.

Comment: @Fran: It is still not optimal. I will edit it later.

Comment: @Marienplatz I compiled your code and it works. But after I applied your code to my source ( `\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\input{my_file.tex}
\end{filecontents*}`) it isn't working! it generates the whole document twice! Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @sajjadG: Read my edit please.

Comment: @Marienplatz Thanks you very much. But I have a little problem with step4. step 3 works fine. but when I use `\usepackage[active,tightpage,floats]{preview}` to create a pdf of all the tables I get a pdf of all the tables and figures together in a single pdf file. and another problem is that tables are not centered!

Answer (score 4):

Everything between `\begin{Export}{<type>}` and `\end{Export}` is written into an external file with name `\jobname-<type>#.tex`. This one is run from within the document and the created pdf is then used by `\includegraphics`. The `<type>` parameter is not really important, it simplifies only the handling if there are a lot of tabulars and/or figures.  This example creates the external files

```
test.tex         the main document
test-tab1.tex
test-tab1.pdf
test-tab2.tex
test-tab2.pdf
test-fig1.tex
test-fig1.pdf
```

and, of course, the `.log` and `.aux` files, too. The command `\newcommand\WritePreamble{...` must be extended if you need other or more packages for your tabulars and figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{extern}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\FVB@VerbatimOut[1]{%
\@bsphack%
\begingroup
\FV@UseKeyValues%
\FV@DefineWhiteSpace%
\def\FV@Space{\space}%
\FV@DefineTabOut%
\def\FV@ProcessLine##1{%
\toks@{##1}\immediate\write\FV@OutFile{\the\toks@}}%
\immediate\openout\FV@OutFile #1\relax%
\WritePreamble%<<=== write preamble
\let\FV@FontScanPrep\relax
\let\@noligs\relax%
\FV@Scan}
\renewcommand\FVE@VerbatimOut{%<<=== write postamble
\WriteLine{\string\end{document}}% <<
\immediate\closeout\FV@OutFile\endgroup\@esphack}

\newcommand\WriteLine[1]{%
\begingroup%
\let\protect\@unexpandable@protect%
\edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write\FV@OutFile{#1}}%
\reserved@a%
\endgroup}
\makeatother

\newcommand\WritePreamble{%
\WriteLine{\string\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}}%
\WriteLine{\string\usepackage{array}}%
\WriteLine{\string\begin{document}}%
}

\newcommand\Export[1]{%
\stepcounter{extern}%
\gdef\externExt{#1}%
\VerbatimEnvironment%
\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname-#1\theextern.tex}}

\def\endExport{%
\end{VerbatimOut}
\IfFileExists{\jobname-\externExt\theextern.tex}
  {\typeout{>>>running pdflatex with file \jobname-\externExt\theextern.tex}%
   \immediate\write18{pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode \jobname-\externExt\theextern}}
  {\fbox{Error in Export!}}%
\IfFileExists{\jobname-\externExt\theextern.pdf}
    {\includegraphics{\jobname-\externExt\theextern}}
    {\fbox{Error in running \jobname-\externExt\theextern.tex~ Try again}}%
}

\begin{document}

foo

\begin{Export}{tab}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\hline
foo & bar & baz \\\hline
f   & b   & b   \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{Export}

bar

\begin{Export}{fig}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
\begin{picture}(3,3)
\put(1.5,1.5){\circle*{1}}
\end{picture}
\end{Export}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{A caption of a tabular}
\begin{Export}{tab}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\hline
f   & b   & b   \\\hline
foo & bar & baz \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{Export}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Herbert. If we want to use this method to make a separate file of figures and tables, we should go through the main file and place all the figures and tables between `\begin{export}` and `\end{export}` right? If this is the case, it's a good alternative for separating tables codes to files and `\input` then in the text. but for editing a long document, like `\input` it will take so much time to do this.

Comment: You do not need the `\input` command. The table/figure is included by default as a pdf image.

Comment: This is a cool idea, but I ran into the problem that the page width was not carried over.

Comment: @Geoff: modify the line  `\WriteLine{\string\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}}%` to use the article class instead. And add more commands if you have a specific page setting.

Comment: @Herbert: How to convert at the same time the PDFs to svg or png. I've changed the line you mentioned above to 

`\WriteLine{\string\documentclass[border=0pt,convert=pdf2svg]{standalone}}%`

but no conversion is done.

Answer (score 1):

For little documents (articles or so) with all the figures and tables as floats, one possibility is to fix the rules for floats so that these rules cannot be  accomplished. For example:

```
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{1.1} % that is 110% (too much)
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1}
```

So all the floats must move to the end of text. To return to floats placed within the text, simply comment these two lines.

A MWE to test that this approach could work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\title{A MWE}
\author{Fran}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{1.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
\hline
    11 & 12 & 13\\
    21 & 22 & 23\\
    31 & 32 & 33\\
    41 & 42 & 43\\
    51 & 52 & 53\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}


\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6-10]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
\caption{A}\label{a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[16-20]

% Table and figures come here 

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{1.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1}

\end{document}
```

However, this surely will fail in big documents with many floats (typical "Too many unprocessed floats" error).