# How to scale figures and table to text width?

Tags: tables, scaling, resize

I'm inserted figures and tables in my document in the following way:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=110mm]{figure.jpg}
\caption{The caption.}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{The caption.}
\centering
\resizebox{12cm}{!}{\input{table}}
\label{tab:label}
\end{table}
```

The figure and table is larger then the text width, thus I'm resizing it. Of course I can adjust the value so that it fits more or less the text width. But is there a possibility that it is automatically scaled to the text width?

Comment: use `\textwidth` instead of 110mm and 12cm (but scaling tables is __horrible__ )

Comment: `[width=\textwidth]` ou `\resizebox{\textwidth}` should be enough.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much, this worked. What would you do instead of scaling tables? The problem is that the table is too large and does not fit ino the page.

Comment: unlike an image a table is text, you don't make paragraphs of text fit the page by making each line an arbitrary sized font just to make things fit, you choose a suitable size in advance from a small fixed list so different units use the same size (`\normalsize`, `\small`, `\footnotesize` etc) and then arrange linebreaking so the text fits. the same should apply (more so) to tables,

Comment: @David Carlisle What about the idea to scale tables via http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140796/generating-a-separate-pdf-file-of-tables-and-figures-from-a-latex-file ? Create an Image and scale Image could be possible? Am I wrong?

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger it's possible, it's also possible to set the whole document on comic sans in pink on a red background, it doesn't mean the result is necessarily that desirable.

Comment: Oh sorry, it seems to me that I should not have asked this question. It was only an idea for one more solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, you can use use `\textwidth` (or `\columnwidth` for two column documents) instead of specific lengths such as 110mm and 12cm.