# Resizing a table using resizebox raises an error

Tags: tables, resize

I have tables which are quite long because they have between 9 and 25 columns. They don't even fit on a page with a landscape layout. I tried to resize them using resizebox as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10863/is-there-a-way-to-slightly-shrink-a-table-including-font-size-to-fit-within-th) but it always raises an error.

This in my LaTeX-file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \centering
    \settowidth\mywidth{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{TABLENAME}}}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\mywidth}
            \mbox{}\par
            \textbf{\MakeUppercase{TABLENAME}}
        \end{minipage}
    %\[
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{column 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{column 8}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{column 9}}\\
    \midrule
        value & value & value & value & value & value & value & value & value \\
    \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}   
    %\]

    \caption{My Caption}
    \label{tbl:verylongtable}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And the exception I get is

```
pdflatex> ! You can't use '\hrule' here except with leaders
```

When I try to put the whole table environment inside the resizebox (and not only the code inside the table environment) I get the error:

```
pdflatex> ! Not in outer par mode
```

How can I scale my table anyway? I did not found a solution which works yet.
And another side question: I read that in the line

```
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
```

The `%` is important. Why? I only know a percentage sign as a beginning of a comment.

Comment: The reason for the minipage inside the table environment can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274779/need-help-adding-text-next-to-a-table

Comment: Why writing `\MakeUppercase{TABLENAME}`? Seems redundant... Also, `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` is not necessary in your case.

Comment: @Alenanno I wrote a little piece of code which generated me the table environments based on a given file. Not all tablenames are in uppercase there.

Comment: as for your last line the `%` is introducing a comment in that position see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines

Comment: Note that scaling tables should be avoided see this comment from earlier today: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289548/how-to-scale-figures-and-table-to-text-width?noredirect=1#comment700639_289548

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\resizebox` is a horizontal mode command (like `\mbox`) so it can take the `tabular` but not vertical material like `\centering`.

Also please test your example before posting there were undefined commands and extra `}` unrelated to the question asked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}%grrr
\begin{document}
\newlength\mywidth%grrr
\begin{table}[ht]

    \centering
    \settowidth\mywidth{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{TABLENAME}}}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\mywidth}
            \mbox{}\par
            \textbf{\MakeUppercase{TABLENAME}}
        \end{minipage}

    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}[t]{ccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{column 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 2}
%grr}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{column 8}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{column 9}}\\
    \midrule
        value & value & value & value & value & value & value & value & value \\
    \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}}  


    \caption{My Caption}
    \label{tbl:verylongtable}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```