# Spitting out all graphics into separate files

Tags: graphics

I have a paper that has a quite a few TikZ figures as well as quite a few PDF figures (generated in exactly the right size by some Matplotlib scripts). The journal we ended up wanting to submit to has some pretty ridiculous (§) requirements, including the demand that every figure be submitted separately as a TIFF.

Does anyone have any suggestions for automatically splitting out all included PDFs and all generated TikZ pictures in a way that allows me to automate this? I would prefer if the *entire* figure environment, except the caption, is output, so [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134733/splitting-figures-tables-into-separate-files) does not quite apply.

---

(§) And I quote their "advice" (I'm not joking):

1. Compile the LaTeX files into a PDF.
2. Open the PDF in Photoshop, GIMP, or another graphics program that enables TIFF.
3. Crop out the figure and export as TIFF.

Comment: Not sure if I get you right. Do you mean that all included files are TIFF and included by `\includegraphics{xxx.tiff}`?

Comment: If they want a TIFF copy for every included figure, you can simply export all Ti*k*Z figures and run a imagemagick to convert all PDFs to TIFFs at once.

Comment: @Symbol1: Right, but they really want all subfigures in one TIFF, so is there a way I can dump out each and every figure environment (minus caption)?

Comment: Both `preview` and `standalone` have the function that "you say an environment, I typeset it". What you will get is a PDF containing all figures as pages. And the rest is possible with imagemagick.

Comment: Have you considered Perl?