# Extract floats and read an external aux file to get hyperref infos in captions

Tags: floats, auxiliary-files

My purpose is to use the `endfloat` package to extract all figures (with their captions) in a separate `pdf` file. I want to do it with a script combining bash command line and emacs-lisp.

I want to do that because, in my copy editor work, I need to compare the figures (and their captions) of the accepted version with the formatted version ones. I know this is not the perfect solution (but I think it should works in most cases) so different/better ideas are welcome.

This is my MWE (the `mydoc.tex` file):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
,citecolor=blue
,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\label{section1}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Dummy caption \cite{1} (see figure~\ref{fig3} in
      section~\ref{section3}).\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 2}
\label{section2}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Dummy caption \cite{2} (see figure~\ref{fig1} in
      section~\ref{section1}).\label{fig2}}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 3}
\label{section3}
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Dummy caption \cite{3} (see figure~\ref{fig2}
      section~\ref{section2}).\label{fig3}}
\end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{1}
Dummy bibibtem

\bibitem{2}
Dummy bibibtem

\bibitem{3}
Dummy bibibtem

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. First of all I want to generate and backup the `.aux` file. I'll compile with:

   ```
   latexmk -pdf mydoc.tex; cp mydoc.aux mydoc-bk.aux
   ```
2. Then I'll compile with:

   ```
   pdflatex "\nofiles"\
   "\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage[figuresonly,nolists]{endfloat}}"\
   "\nonstopmode"\
   "\input{mydoc.tex}"
   ```

to generate the `mydoc.fff` file that contains:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.49\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Dummy caption \cite{1} (see figure~\ref{fig3} in
    section~\ref{section3}).\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}
\efloatseparator

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.49\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Dummy caption \cite{2} (see figure~\ref{fig1} in
    section~\ref{section1}).\label{fig2}}
\end{figure}
\efloatseparator

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.49\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{Dummy caption \cite{3} (see figure~\ref{fig2}
    section~\ref{section2}).\label{fig3}}
\end{figure}
\efloatseparator
```

Now I create a new file: `mynewdoc.tex` (this is meant to be a temporary solution):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
,citecolor=blue
,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\def\efloatseparator{\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\input{mydoc.fff}

\end{document}
```

That I'll compile with:

```
pdflatex mynewdoc.tex
```

**My question is:** can I force (pdf)latex to compile using the backup `.aux` file so to get the correct refs (obviously without working links) in my final pdf?

I think that should be disabled the writing of the `.aux` file in some way because some of the `labels` are already defined in the external `.aux` file.

> **My solution.** I resolved by renaming the `.aux` I want to be read in `mynewdoc.aux` and putting `\nofiles` in the preamble.

**Alternative solution.** I also found this alternative solution using the `xcomment` package. After generating the correct `.aux` file I will compile with:

```
pdflatex -jobname=mydoc \
"\RequirePackage{xcomment} \xcomment{figure}"\
"\nofiles"\
"\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldendfigure\endfigure"\
"\def\endfigure{\oldendfigure\clearpage}}"\
"\input{mydoc.tex}"
```

I'll have a warning becouse the `\nofiles` command does not take effect (can anybody help me with that?) but the generated `pdf` file will be ok.

Comment: This should be something the xr package could do.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you. I didn't know about `xr` package. Unfortunately it doesn't work because same of the labels defined in my new file (e.g. "fig1") are already defined in the external `.aux` file. Furthermore `xr` package doesn't handle `\cite`/\bibtem` commands (I think).

Comment: "some" of the labels...

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: The `xr` package provides `\externaldocument[foo:]{foofile}` command, where `foofile` is an external `.tex` file that has been compiled already. You can use the same label names (if needed) in all files, say, `fig:supernova` and refer to it with `\ref{fig:supernova}` in the main document and `\ref{foo:fig:supernova}`, i.e. the `foo:` from the optional argument of `\externaldocument` macro is prepended with this prefix `foo:`. Basically, the prefix can be chosen arbitrarily

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you. I saw that. But what about `\cite*` commands? I think that xr can handle only `\ref` commands.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: Your document was about `\label` and `\ref`, not about `\cite`, wasn't it? Anyway, see the package `xcite` for this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No It wasn't. I took care to put  also `\cite` commands in the captions to include all possible issues. But `xcite` is a good hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I wrote two Bash scripts that do the same thing.

1. Using the `endfloat` package (I named it ExtractFiguresEndfloat.sh):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   TexFile=$1

   latexmk -pdf $TexFile

   pdflatex "\nofiles"\
   "\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage[figuresonly,nolists]{endfloat}}"\
   "\nonstopmode"\
   "\input{$TexFile}"

   pdflatex "\def\efloatseparator{\clearpage}"\
   "\nofiles"\
   "\let\olddocument\document"\
   "\renewcommand{\document}{\olddocument\input{\jobname.fff}\enddocument}"\
   "\nonstopmode\input{$TexFile}"
   ```

   usage:

   ```
   ExtractFiguresEndfloat.sh file.tex
   ```
2. Using the `xcomment` package (I named it ExtractFiguresXcomment.sh):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   TexFile=$1
   PREPRINT_ID=`basename $TexFile .tex`

   latexmk -pdf $TexFile

   pdflatex -jobname=$PREPRINT_ID \
   "\RequirePackage{xcomment} \xcomment{figure}"\
   "\nofiles"\
   "\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldendfigure\endfigure"\
   "\def\endfigure{\oldendfigure\clearpage}}"\
   "\nonstopmode"\
   "\input{$TexFile}"
   ```

   usage:

   ```
   ExtractFiguresXcomment.sh file.tex
   ```

I tested on a few files and they work (the first one has a limitation because `endfloat` wants the `\end{figure}` string to be placed at line beginning...).

I get:

[image]