# Input a file ignoring the main body by command line

Tags: environments, compiling

This question is relate do this one: [Extract floats and read an external aux file to get hyperref infos in captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383100/33634).

In simple terms I want to use the `preamble` and the `.aux` file of a document to compile and external file. In my case the file `.fff` created by  the `endfloat` package.

Starting with this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
,citecolor=blue
,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\label{section1}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Dummy caption \cite{1} (see figure~\ref{fig3} in
      section~\ref{section3}).\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 2}
\label{section2}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Dummy caption \cite{2} (see figure~\ref{fig1} in
      section~\ref{section1}).\label{fig2}}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 3}
\label{section3}
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Dummy caption \cite{3} (see figure~\ref{fig2}
      section~\ref{section2}).\label{fig3}}
\end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{1}
Dummy bibibtem

\bibitem{2}
Dummy bibibtem

\bibitem{3}
Dummy bibibtem

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

and using the `endfloat` package I generate the `.fff` file. I do it passing the `endfloat` package and options by command line:

```
pdflatex "\nofiles"\
"\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage[figuresonly,nolists]{endfloat}}"\
"\nonstopmode"\
"\input{mydoc.tex}"
```

Now I want to do something like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
,citecolor=blue
,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{comment}
\nofiles
\def\efloatseparator{\clearpage}
\begin{document}
\input{mydoc.fff}
\begin{comment}
...
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

But by command line! (I don't want to create a separate `.tex` file) I'm close enough to the solution as this command string works:

```
pdflatex "\def\efloatseparator{\clearpage}"\
"\nofiles"\
"\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{comment}}"\
"\let\olddocument\document"\
"\let\oldenddocument\enddocument\"
"\renewenvironment{document}{\olddocument\input{mydoc.fff}}{\oldenddocument}"\
"\input{mydoc.tex}"
```

but I'm not able to comment the doc contents.

I also get this warning:

```
Package auxhook Warning: Cannot patch \document,
(auxhook)                using \AtBeginDocument instead.
```

that make me suspect I'm doing very bad... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont' no how "evil" is the solution I found but it works for my purposes:

```
pdflatex "\def\efloatseparator{\clearpage}"\
"\nofiles"\
"\let\olddocument\document"\
"\renewcommand{\document}{\olddocument\input{\jobname.fff}\enddocument}"\
"\nonstopmode\input{mydoc.tex}"
```

indeed I get a `.pdf` file generated using the preamble and the `.aux` file of my master `.tex` file but with just the external file contents (in this case the figures with their captions).