# Export each figure as a separate PDF-file

Tags: floats, input, export

I am using `.pdf_tex` files to insert and label figures in LaTeX:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \graphicspath{{Graphics/FiltersCa/}}
    \input{Graphics/FiltersCa/COMB_filter_activeZ2b.pdf_tex
    }
    \caption{...
    }
    \label{fig:FiltersCa}
\end{figure}
```

Is it possible to export each figure as a separate PDF-file?

Comment: I don’t think so. The compiler only produces one PDF. So you’d have to make a script in a different language that divided it up into multiple .tex-files.

Comment: Maybe you can find some useful information here: [Generating a separate pdf file of tables and figures from a latex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140796/134144) and here: [Splitting figures/tables into separate files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134733/134144)

Comment: thanks for your answer....I had a look at the work-arounds. I was just wondering, if there is a easier way. I need to use an online compiler that fails compiling my figures using .pdt_tex-files. Therefore I need to create complete figures, i can just include.

Comment: If you have just a couple of pictures then maybe have a look at the `standalone` package *and* document class: https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The endfloat package will export all the figures (LaTeX source) to a `.fff` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\efloat@openpost{fff}
\efloat@iwrite{fff}{\string\textwidth=\the\textwidth}% pass \textwidth to fff file
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Test caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Standalone can create a PDF file containing one figure/page.  Labels and counter values will be lost.

```
\documentclass[multi=figure]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}%
{\def\@captype{figure}%
\minipage{\textwidth}}%
{\endminipage}
\makeatother

\let\efloatseparator=\empty

\begin{document}
\input{test5.fff}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This version loses the caption.

```
\documentclass[multi=figure]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewenvironment{figure}{\ignorespaces}{\unskip}
\renewcommand{\caption}[2][]{\ignorespaces}
\let\efloatseparator=\empty

\begin{document}
\input{test5.fff}% previously created fff file
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost perfect solution. Is there now a simple way to suppress the caption of each figure with one command at the beginning of the document. I would like to have the figures in the final PDF without caption and don't want to change everywhere caption to caption*.

<\captionsetup{format=empty}> doesn't work for me :/

Comment: \renewcommand{\caption}[2][default]{\ignorespaces}  should take care of it.  If you are losing the caption, you don't need the minipage either.

Answer (score 2):

Quick update with my current work-around (figure-by-figure):

- I open the original `PDF`-output with `Inkscape` (I recommend Poppler/Cairo import). You can select the page containing a specific figure.
- Create an rectangle (`F4`) that outlines the region of the page, you would like to export (Figure with or without caption).
- Press `Shift` and click on the imported `PDF`-page and the rectangle.
- Right mouse click on the rectangle and choose `Set Clip`
- Press `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`D`, click on `Resize page to content...` in the `Custom size` section and click `Resize page to rawing or selection`
- In the `File`-menu, you can safe it as a `PNG` or `PDF` file. For `PDF` I would suggest to `Convert text to path` in order to maintain the original `LaTeX` font.

Best wishes,
Markus