# Splitting multiple tikz pics into individual output files

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've got a .tex file with about 200 tikzpictures (and nothing else apart from spacing elements) in it and I'm trying to find a way for each one to go into its own individual output file (pdf, but I guess it could be a different format), instead of lumping all of them into the same file.

Does anyone know a smart way to do this? I'm trying to avoid having to make 200 separate .tex files. In case people need to know the context in order to help me find a solution, I'm using latex to create cards for boardgames, and though it's generally better to have all cards from a game together in a single file, sometimes it's necessary to get them as one card per file. I'm compiling with latexmk and xelatex, if that makes any difference.

Comment: You can uses `externalize` or just include them as `standalone` files.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thanks, externalize works, it just takes a very long time to compile (6 minutes instead of 12s). Subsequent recompiles take the normal 12s though, so I guess it's ok.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423109/export-each-figure-as-a-separate-pdf-file/423253?r=SearchResults&s=10|24.9952#423253  Technically it is still one file, but you can use [page=...] to select individual images.