# Size of tikz picture like \textwidth or \pagewidth

Tags: tikz-pgf, width, height

I want to make picture with tikz, and then fill background with something.

To do it properly, I want to get the size of picture (height and width).
Is there a command that will give me whole size of picture, something working like `\textwidth`?

I'm doing genealogy tree using genealogytree package, so here is something like MWE. I'm copying the way to add background to image,  from example from title page of manual.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree[template=signpost]
        {
            child{
            g{A}
            p{B}
            c{C}
            c{D}
            c{E}
        }
        }
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node (bg) [fill tile image*={width=4cm}{crinklepaper.png},
            minimum width=5cm, minimum height=5cm,
            inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current bounding box) {};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting something like this

[image]

Background is too high and too narrow.

Well, I of course can fine-tune it and write smaller height and bigger width. But it will change the moment I will add something to my genealogy tree.

Is there a way to like export the width of image the way we can export the `\textwidth` in normal documents?

I want to change `minimum width=5cm, minimum height=5cm,` with `minimum width=\picturewidth, minimum height=\pictureheight,`

Comment: You can print \the\textrwidth and \the\textheight for a given document class, then use those values to create a minipage with the right dimentsions.  Some what related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423109/export-each-figure-as-a-separate-pdf-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tikz` library `fit`:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree[template=signpost]
        {
            child{
            g{A}
            p{B}
            c{C}
            c{D}
            c{E}
        }
        }
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node (bg) [
                fill tile image={crinklepaper.png},
                fit=(current bounding box),
                inner sep=3pt
            ] {};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Love you, thank you very much!