# How to Neutralize TikZpicture Codings without Deleting Them?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-pic

I have a document which contains over one hundred tikzpictures similar to the ones seen below.

I would like to (easily, if possible) produce two different documents from that set of code---(1) as it is; and (2) everything but the tikzpictures.

I know that I could copy the document code and then manually delete all 100+ tikzpictures---but I am hoping there is a better way to produce what I am looking for.

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}
\textwidth=4.25in \textheight=7.0in \voffset -7pt

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{197,213,255}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\parskip 10pt
\lipsum[13]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
%pencildraw,
draw,fill=lightblue,text width=0.85\textwidth,inner sep=4mm]
{\begin{minipage}{3.42in} \footnotesize
\selectfont \textbf{\lipsum[13]} \hfill \textbf{\emph{---L. Iipsum}} \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[13]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
%pencildraw,
draw,fill=lightblue,text width=0.85\textwidth,inner sep=4mm]
{\begin{minipage}{3.42in} \footnotesize
\selectfont \textbf{\lipsum[13]} \hfill \textbf{\emph{---L. Iipsum}} \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[13]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
%pencildraw,
draw,fill=lightblue,text width=0.85\textwidth,inner sep=4mm]
{\begin{minipage}{3.42in} \footnotesize
\selectfont \textbf{\lipsum[13]} \hfill \textbf{\emph{---L. Iipsum}} \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: Is there a (reasonably simple) way to modify the above code so that LaTeX does not execute the `tikzpicture` codings and just the text appears in the output? (I compile the code with `pdflatex`.)

Thank you.

Comment: You can use e.g. package multiaudience: https://ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience , or other ones from cond-comp: https://ctan.org/topic/cond-comp . E.g. with multiaudience you'd define two groups (of readers) and encapsulate your tikzpictures as needed. Yes, it's a lot of work. // If you want to automate it, I fear you'll need to do some kind of scripting, e.g. to find and delete all these environmenst, and finally save to a second doc. For practical reasons the full version should be the master, and the extract generated as needed dynamically. Consider PERL etc. for this.

Comment: You could use standalone to put the tikzpictures into a file by themselves, one per page.  Then is is just a decision on whether to include them.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423109/export-each-figure-as-a-separate-pdf-file/423253?r=SearchResults&s=11%7C26.9056#423253

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for the link; however, my (real) document is in book class. I'm not sure it will work for me.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine in book class, but the other solutions are simpler.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you. That is good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With package `environ` and command `\RenewEnviron` :

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}
\textwidth=4.25in \textheight=7.0in \voffset -7pt

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{197,213,255}


\usepackage{environ}  %change
\RenewEnviron{tikzpicture}{}{}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\parskip 10pt
\lipsum[13]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
%pencildraw,
draw,fill=lightblue,text width=0.85\textwidth,inner sep=4mm]
{\begin{minipage}{3.42in} \footnotesize
\selectfont \textbf{\lipsum[13]} \hfill \textbf{\emph{---L. Iipsum}} \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[13]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
%pencildraw,
draw,fill=lightblue,text width=0.85\textwidth,inner sep=4mm]
{\begin{minipage}{3.42in} \footnotesize
\selectfont \textbf{\lipsum[13]} \hfill \textbf{\emph{---L. Iipsum}} \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[13]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
%pencildraw,
draw,fill=lightblue,text width=0.85\textwidth,inner sep=4mm]
{\begin{minipage}{3.42in} \footnotesize
\selectfont \textbf{\lipsum[13]} \hfill \textbf{\emph{---L. Iipsum}} \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it can have collateral effects, I can't extensively test now, but it works in the MWE: add

`\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tikzpicture}{o +b}{}{}`

just before `\begin{document}`. It basically redefine the `tikzpicture` environment to do nothing.

You can easily add a "signpost" also, like

`\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tikzpicture}{o +b}{\par***Removed tikzpicture***\par}{}` or something like that.

Commenting in/out that line would toggle the compilation of tikzpicures or not.

[image]