Export a panel of figures as a PDF
I have three distinct PDFs, each containing a different figure, i.e.
(1) example-image-a.pdf,
(2) example-image-b.pdf,
(3) example-image-c.pdf,
and forming a panel of figures, through the following commands:
\begin{figure}
...
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.pdf}
...
\end{figure}

(similarly, for instance, to Multiple panel figure, with figures side by side).
Would it be possible to export the whole "combined" panel of figures (resulting after compiling Latex), as a PDF?

Edited:
As suggested, I used the endfloat package to export the figure, from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423139/333470, but it does not produce any .fff file (I am using Overleaf), and therefore I am not able to export the figure as a single PDF:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage[subrefformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\efloat@openpost{fff}
\efloat@iwrite{fff}{\string\textwidth=\the\textwidth}% pass \textwidth to fff file
\makeatother




\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{subcaptiongroup}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=11.5cm]{example-image-a}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (13cm,-0.5cm) {a};
        \phantomcaption\label{my_fig_a}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \\
    \vspace{0.2cm}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=11.5cm]{example-image-b}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (13cm,-0.8cm) {b};
        \phantomcaption\label{my_fig_b}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{subcaptiongroup}
    \captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
    \caption{
    \subref{my_fig_a} 
    This is my figure 1(a).
    \subref{my_fig_b}
    This is my figure 1(b).
    }
    \label{my_fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


My desired output is to have the following panel called "Figure 1", formed by "Figure 1(a)" and "Figure 1(b)", exported as a PDF file, i.e. Figure1.pdf:


I guess you are searching for standalone or preview. But this is only a guess, because it is not clear what you mean with export. Maybe also pdfjam resp. pdfpages (see option nup) could be a solution.

Thanks for your comment... Since Latex combines a group of Figures (i.e. Figure 1(a), Figure 1(b), Figure 1(c)), to form a panel of figures (e.g. Figure 1), I would like to export the resulting panel, i.e. the whole Figure 1, as a PDF and save it in a folder outside Latex

but what is your question? If you made a document just containing the code you show (possibly without the figure environment) and saved the resulting pdf, isn't that all you need?

Have you read the documentation of the linked packages? Have you read the answer(s) to the linked question? What is your concrete problem? Can you show what you've tried so far?

Well, i try to explain better... I have a long article... In this article there are several panels of figures, i.e. groups of figures, where, for example, Figure 1 is composed of 3 Figures, i.e. Figure 1(a), Figure 1(b), and Figure 1(c). The journal asked to provide the entire Figure 1, the entire Figure 2, the entire Figure 3, etc, since they are panels of figures, and they don't want the single Figure 1(a), Figure 1(b), Figure 1(c), Figure 2(a), Figure 2(b), Figure 3(a), and so on. Therefore, o asked if there is a way to export the entire panels of Figures as they appear after compilation..

@cabohah, I am reading what you suggested, but it looks like that in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423109/export-each-figure-as-a-separate-pdf-file, there is only one \includegraphics to export, but in my case there are at least two of them for each panel of figures... I am checking everything you sent me, but I am not super fast :-) also, i cannot show what i tried because i had no idea what to try so far... It was just a general question to understand what I could try...

In this moment I cannot make several tries, please don't cancel this question up to tomorrow, so I can see if the solution in the other question works also for me or if my case is different

endfloat exports whole floats, i.e., figure environments not single \includgraphics commands. So I don't see your problem in using the answer to the similar question. But if you still believe it’s different, please edit the question and add a minimal working example that makes it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

And if you just want to combine the three \includegraphics commands into a new PDF, the already linked packages should help you. If not, please edit the question and add a minimal working example that shows what you tried and why, e.g., standalone does not help you.

If endfloat exports whole floats, regardless the number of \includegraphics forming a panel, ok I go for it and you can close this question.. just a doubt about something i cannot find - yet - online.. Can endfloat export all the figures "in one shot" from the document, in such a way that i dont need to apply endfloat to all the panels I need to export, one by one?

Thanks a lot for all your comments and suggestions @cabohah! I will try all those solutions as soon as possible :-)

the command \makeatletter \efloat@openpost{fff} \efloat@iwrite{fff}{\string\textwidth=\the\textwidth}% pass \textwidth to fff file \makeatother from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423253/333470 does not create any .fff file in Overleaf. Therefore, the endfloat solution does not work for me.

With your example named main.tex I get a file main.fff with the contents \textwidth=345.0pt plus the figure environment. Note, that this is kind of auxiliary file, so I don't know, whether Overleaf shows such files in the source panel (AFAIK usually not). But this would be an Overleaf problem not a LaTeX problem.

Thanks a lot for your comment

Overleaf does store files created during compilation, you can find them next to the compile button at "Logs and output files" and then in the bottom right "Other logs and files". Then the duplicate solution can be used, I just checked it and it works fine with the subfigures from this question as well.

Thanks a lot @Marijn!! I did not know about this feature of Overleaf!
